# Databinding with Kotlin and generics. error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to List

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I bind a `List` of `Interfaces` with a type argument via databinding.

Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {

    T getValue();

}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel {

    public ObservableField<List<MyInterface>> name = new ObservableField<>();

}
```

BindingAdapter:

```
@android.databinding.BindingAdapter("bind")
public static void bind(TextView textView, List<MyInterface> list) {    
}
```

XML:

```
<data>

    <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.myname.playground4.MyViewModel"/>

</data>


<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:bind="@{viewModel.name}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

**This works as long as the `ViewModel` is in Java.**

When I convert the `ViewModel` to Kotlin:

```
class MyKotlinViewModel {
    val name = ObservableField<List<MyInterface<*>>>()
}
```

I get an error in my `ActivityMainBindingImpl.java`:

> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to List

Here's the faulty method:

```
@Override
protected void executeBindings() {
    long dirtyFlags = 0;
    synchronized(this) {
        dirtyFlags = mDirtyFlags;
        mDirtyFlags = 0;
    }
    android.databinding.ObservableField viewModelName = null;
    java.util.List viewModelNameGet = null;
    com.example.fweigl.playground4.MyKotlinViewModel viewModel = mViewModel;

    if ((dirtyFlags & 0x7L) != 0) {



            if (viewModel != null) {
                // read viewModel.name
                viewModelName = viewModel.getName();
            }
            updateRegistration(0, viewModelName);


            if (viewModelName != null) {
                // read viewModel.name.get()
                viewModelNameGet = viewModelName.get(); // error is here
            }
    }
    // batch finished
    if ((dirtyFlags & 0x7L) != 0) {
        // api target 1

        com.example.fweigl.playground4.BindingAdapter.bind(this.mboundView0, viewModelNameGet);
    }
}
```

**Anyone know the reason for this and / or how to fix this?**

You can try for yourself with my test project @ https://github.com/fmweigl/playground4. The (working) java version is on branch 'master', the (non-working) kotlin version on branch 'kotlin'.

Comment: This sounds like something that should be a [bug filed against Data Binding](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192721).

Comment: @ianhanniballake Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is about your BindingAdapter.In Kotlin you have to add         `@JvmStatic` annotation to top of your BindingAdapter.

Like this:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("bind")
fun bind(recyclerView: RecyclerView, items: MutableList<SmartResult>) {
     //Anything that you wanna do ...
}
```

Because when your `ViewModel` an `XML` want to use of your binding adapter it has to be static like in java!

Comment: The BindingAdapter is in Java and static and works with a Java ViewModel. Good idea though!